# Target name macro in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

how can i make the output name in visual studio project based on in-code macro or variable like libUI.dll and libnewUI.dll if this is possible how can i do it?
thanks in advance

```
#define NEW_UI
#ifdef NEW_UI
// output name libnewUI.dll
#else
// output name libUI.dll
#endif
```

edit:
current solution
using 2 build configurations with macros

Project -> Properties -> Configuration Manger Add new configuration
then you can change your "TargetName" for output name to current configuration

if you using macros

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor Add your macro to current configuration

and build using this 2 configurations
[Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZdi8.png)

if someone know better solution please add it here

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: Is there a Visual Studio IDE variable for this? If so perhaps you can create a preprocessor definition.